# Clone a given branch with LibGit2Sharp

Tags: git, libgit2sharp

I would like to clone a given branch to local repository using LibGit2Sharp.

```
 var repoPath = LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Clone("https://something", localpath, cloneOptions);

 using (var repo = new LibGit2Sharp.Repository(repoPath))
 {
     var branches = repo.Branches.GetEnumerator();
 }
```

With repo.Branches.GetEnumerator() I can see every remote branches, but with the Clone command I can clone only the master branch from GitHub? How can I clone the "testBranch" or something?

Actually, by default, `Clone()` takes care of locally retrieving all commits of all branches. By default, only the remote HEAD branch (generally `origin/master`), gets an automatically created local branch counterpart, which is then checked out.

So, once the clone is performed, all you have have got to do is creating a local branch from the remote branch you'd like to work this and check this newly created one out.

For instance, given you're interested in the branch `my-feature-branch` and that your remote is named `origin`:

```
Branch remoteBranch = repo.Branches["origin/my-feature-branch"];

Branch newLocalBranch = repo.CreateBranch("my-feature-branch");

// Make the local branch track the upstream one
repo.Branches.Update(newLocalBranch ,
     b => b.TrackedBranch = remoteBranch.CanonicalName);

Branch trackingBranch = repo.Branches["my-feature-branch"];

repo.Checkout(trackingBranch);
```

FWIW, there's a pending **[Pull Request](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/pull/650)** to allow the user to explictly specify the branch one would like to see checked out.

**EDIT**

I updated my code with your suggestions, but it still not working well. The content of my local repository isn't equal with the trackingBranch, it's still representing the content of the master branch.

```
var remoteBranch = repo.Branches["origin/" + branchName];

var newLocalBranch = repo.Branches.Add(branchName, commit, true);

repo.Branches.Update(newLocalBranch, 
      b => b.TrackedBranch = remoteBranch.CanonicalName);

var trackingBranch = repo.Branches[branchName];

repo.Checkout(trackingBranch, new LibGit2Sharp.CheckoutOptions(), author);
```

Comment: `repo.Branches.Add(branchName, commit, true);` -> where does `commit` come from? I'd rather recommend using the `IRepository.CreateBranch()` extension method or `repo.Branches.Add(branchName, remoteBranch.Tip);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, by default, `Clone()` takes care of locally retrieving all commits of all branches. By default, only the remote HEAD branch (generally `origin/master`), gets an automatically created local branch counterpart, which is then checked out.

So, once the clone is performed, all you have have got to do is creating a local branch from the remote branch you'd like to work this and check this newly created one out.

For instance, given you're interested in the branch `my-feature-branch` and that your remote is named `origin`:

```
Branch remoteBranch = repo.Branches["origin/my-feature-branch"];

Branch newLocalBranch = repo.CreateBranch("my-feature-branch", remoteBranch.Tip);

// Make the local branch track the upstream one
repo.Branches.Update(newLocalBranch ,
     b => b.TrackedBranch = remoteBranch.CanonicalName);

Branch trackingBranch = repo.Branches["my-feature-branch"];

repo.Checkout(trackingBranch);
```

FWIW, there's a pending **[Pull Request](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/pull/650)** to allow the user to explictly specify the branch one would like to see checked out.

### Update

The Pull Request has been merged. Checking out a known branch after the Clone() call succeeded can now be done, more easily, through:

```
string clonedRepoPath = Repository.Clone(
    url, targetPath,
    new CloneOptions { BranchName = branchName });
```

Comment: Yes, I saw recommending the repo.CreateBranch() method for this problem. I have a LibGit2Sharp with version 0.20.0.0, added to my project by NuGet Package Manager. It's interesing because my Repository object doesn't have a CrateBranch() method. May I did something wrong?

Comment: `CreateBranch()` is an extension method of the `IRepository` interface. It should be exposed by any instance of the `Repository` type.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I didn' use using LibGit2Sharp; at usings and if you just write var repo = new LibGit2Sharp.Repository(path) you cannot use repo.CreateBranch() method.

Comment: It looks like the pull request referenced in this answer has been merged into the product.  I haven't tested the usage yet, but it appears that they now allow you to specify a branch in the CloneOptions object passed into the Repository.Clone command.